# Ionic 4 / Angular 6 : Nested child routes in tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ionic4

I generated an app with the Ionic Tabs Component.

Tabs are **Deliveries**, **About** and **Contact**.

Then I generated a page **Details**.

I would like the page **Details** to be a child of **Deliveries** tab.

Meaning when I'm on a **details** page, I'm navigating through the **deliveries** tab.

Someone asked a similar question on [Ionic Forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577779/ionic-4-angular-6-nested-child-routes-in-tabs)

The directory structure generated :

```
- about
- contact
- deliveries
    deliveries.module.ts
- details
    details.module.ts
- tabs
    tabs.module.ts
    tabs.page.html
    tabs.router.module.ts
app.module.ts
app-routing.module.ts
```

This is the generated **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This is the generated **tabs.router.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { DeliveriesPage } from '../deliveries/deliveries.page';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about.page';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(deliveries:deliveries)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'deliveries',
        outlet: 'deliveries',
        component: DeliveriesPage
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        outlet: 'about',
        component: AboutPage
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        outlet: 'contact',
        component: ContactPage
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(deliveries:deliveries)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

This is a generated **tabs.page.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="Deliveries" icon="bicycle" href="/tabs/(deliveries:deliveries)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="deliveries"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="About" icon="information-circle" href="/tabs/(about:about)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="about"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Contact" icon="contacts" href="/tabs/(contact:contact)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="contact"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This is a generated **deliveries.module.ts**

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DeliveriesPage } from './deliveries.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: DeliveriesPage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    DeliveriesPage
  ]
})
export class DeliveriesPageModule {}
```

This is **details.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { DetailsPage } from './details.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DetailsPage,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [DetailsPage]
})
export class DetailsPageModule {}
```

So, all my attempts failed, I tried to follow the same logic as above.

I tried to work in **deliveries.module.ts**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: DeliveriesPage,
  },
  {
    path: 'details',
    loadChildren: '../details/details.module#DetailsPageModule'
  }
]),
```

I also tried

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: DeliveriesPage,
  },
  {
    path: 'details',
    outlet: 'deliveries
    loadChildren: '../details/details.module#DetailsPageModule'
  }
]),
```

Or

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: DeliveriesPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'details',
        loadChildren: '../details/details.module#DetailsPageModule'
      }
    ]
  },
]),
```

Can't find a way to access details page from

- /tabs/(deliveries:deliveries)/details
- /tabs/(deliveries:details)

Is it possible to achieve that? It is a little bit confusing.

The easy way right now to access **details** page is to define the route in 
**app-routing.module.ts**, but it would not be part of the same router outlet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [4.0.0-beta.18](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta18-2018-12-13) ion-tab was removed and it's not necessary to use named outlets.

**Demo** (with two different approaches) + **Explanation**:
https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tab-routing

Ionic CLI version **4.10.3**
Ionic Framework @ionic/angular **4.0.1**

Answer (score 8):

This all seemed extremely confusing to me.
Then i realised that all i had to do in Tabs Routing was.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'tab1', loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#tab1Module'},
      { path: 'tab2', 
        children: [
          { path: '', loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#tab2Module'},
          { path: ':ID', loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2details.module#tab2detailsModule'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Where Tab2 has a List Page and a details page.

List Page URL : /tabs/tab2

Details Page URL : /tabs/tab2/123/

The Tab2 Tab stays active when your on the list or details page, and the back button shows up when your on the details page.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did. In **tabs.router.module.ts**,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'featured',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab-featured/tab-featured.module#TabFeaturedPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'featured/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab-featured-detail/tab-featured-detail.module#TabFeaturedDetailPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'categories',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab-category/tab-category.module#TabCategoryPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'popular',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab-popular/tab-popular.module#TabPopularPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/featured',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/featured',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

**tab-featured-detail.module.ts**

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TabFeaturedDetailPage } from './tab-featured-detail.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: TabFeaturedDetailPage }])
  ],
  declarations: [TabFeaturedDetailPage]
})
export class TabFeaturedDetailPageModule {}
```

Comment: Hi, could we see what is in tab-featured-detail.module or any other module? Does it contain more nested routes? Cheers.

Comment: tab-featured-detail.module does not contain more nested routes. In my example above, I am making a master-detail pattern for featured, but I had problem setting up the routes until I found your solution. And eventually I just make featured-detail to be same level as featured. This might not be the perfect solution, but it does work for me. I will add in my tab-featured-detail-module.

Answer (score 2):

So this is the cleanest way I found so far to do it.

Here the **tabs.router.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { DeliveriesPage } from '../deliveries/deliveries.page';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about.page';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact.page';
import { DetailsPage } from '../details/details.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(deliveries:deliveries)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'deliveries',
        outlet: 'deliveries',
        component: DeliveriesPage,
      },
      {
        path: 'details/:id',
        outlet: 'deliveries',
        component: DetailsPage
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        outlet: 'about',
        component: AboutPage
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        outlet: 'contact',
        component: ContactPage
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(deliveries:deliveries)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Import the DetailsModulePage in **tabs.module.ts**

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { TabsPageRoutingModule } from './tabs.router.module';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { ContactPageModule } from '../contact/contact.module';
import { AboutPageModule } from '../about/about.module';
import { DeliveriesPageModule } from '../deliveries/deliveries.module';
import { DetailsPageModule } from '../details/details.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TabsPageRoutingModule,
    DeliveriesPageModule,
    AboutPageModule,
    ContactPageModule,
    DetailsPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

Here the **DetailsModulePage** (pretty basic)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { DetailsPage } from './details.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DetailsPage,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [DetailsPage]
})
export class DetailsPageModule {}
```

And this is the way to access DetailsPage

- /tabs/(deliveries:details/2)

If you have a better way to do it, i'll be happy know it.